# How to get notified when multiple workers complete a job with an unknown size?

Tags: python, web-crawler, worker, django-rq

I'm trying to create a web site crawler in Python using [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq). So far my worker looks like this:

1. Get the next page from the queue.
2. Create a page record in the database. Set `status=1`.
3. Download the page contents and process. Might take up to a minute or so.
4. For each link in the page

   1. Check if the link is already registered in the database.
   2. If not, create a new page record. Set `status=0` and add the link to the queue.
5. After the for loop ends, check whether the count of pages with status=0 is 0. If yes, the job is done.

*`status=1` means the page is processed. `status=0` means the page is not processed yet.*

Now, this algorithm works just OK with a single worker. However, it does not when there are more workers becuase the end of job routine is sometimes triggered earlier than it should be.

What is the right way to implement this worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Tweak your current system

- If you hold off setting a page's status to 1 until **after** you have finished processing it then your workers shouldn't declare 'job done' early.
- Your step 2 is only necessary for the very first page that you start crawling with.

So your system would be like:

```
start job:
1. Create a page record in the database. Set status=0. Add page to queue.

worker:
1. Get the next page from the queue.
2. Download the page contents and process. Might take up to a minute or so.
3. For each link in the page
    1. Check if the link is already registered in the database.
    2. If not, create a new page record. Set status=0 and add the link to the queue.
4. After the for loop ends, set status=1 for this page.
5. Check whether the count of pages with status=0 is 0. If yes, the job is done.
```

There is the problem that if a subsequent web crawling job is started before the previous one has finished you will only get 'job done' at the end of the last one.
You could perhaps add a job-id to your database page record and redefine 'job done' as something like `count(status=0 and job-id=x) = 0`

#### 2. Utilise RQ's job class

From the [RQ docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/):

> When jobs get enqueued, the queue.enqueue() method returns a Job instance. 
>   ... it has a convenience result accessor property, that will return None when the job is not yet finished, or a non-None value when the job has finished (assuming the job has a return value in the first place, of course).

You could queue two different types of job, one is 'fetch web page' and another for managing the crawl process.

The management job would initiate and keep track of all the 'fetch web page' jobs. It would know when 'job done' because all of its sub-jobs have completed.

You wouldn't *necessarily* need to write anything to a database to manage the crawl process.

You would need to run 2+ workers so that `crawl` and `fetch` can be worked on at the same time, maybe on separate queues.

```
def something_web_facing():
    ...
    queue.enqueue(crawl, 'http://url.com/start_point.html')
    ...

def crawl(start_url):
    fetch_jobs = []
    seen_urls = set()

    seen_urls.add(start_url)
    fetch_jobs.append( queue.enqueue(fetch, start_url) )

    while len(fetch_jobs) > 0:

        # loop over a copy of fetch_jobs
        for job in list(fetch_jobs):

            # has this job completed yet?
            if job.result:

                # a fetch job returns a list of the next urls to crawl
                for url in job.result:

                    # fetch this url if we haven't seen it before
                    if url not in seen_urls:
                        seen_urls.add(url)
                        fetch_jobs.append( queue.enqueue(fetch, url) )

                fetch_jobs.remove(job)

        time.sleep(1)

    return "Job done!"

def fetch(url):
    """Get web page from url, return a list of links to follow next"""

    html_page = download_web_page(url)
    links_to_follow = find_links_to_follow(html_page)
    return links_to_follow
```

#### 3. Use someone else's web crawler code

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

You could queue up a job that uses scrapy. [Run scrapy from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but couldn't you have an additional table that holds the status of the workers?

I.e., with 10 workers and a state of:
0-8 - "hold"
9 - "working"

From this state, 9 will presumably add more pages to the queue that 0-8 can work on (and change their status in the table to "working").

One other thing to note is that the order of how a worker determines its state needs to be precise:

1. Get the next page from the queue.
2. Create a page record in the database. Set status=1.
3. Download the page contents and process. Might take up to a minute or so.
4. For each link in the page

   1. Check if the link is already registered in the database.
      2.If not, create a new page record. Set status=0 and add the link to the queue.
5. Check to see if there are any pages in the queue.
6. If not, go into wait state.

If a worker is in a wait state, it's order of actions might look something like:

1. Wake up
2. If there are jobs in the queue, go into a "working" state
3. If not, check to see if all workers are in a "hold" state.
4. If so, exit.

Any worker that is in a "hold" state should periodically check to see if there are any workers with a status of "working".  If so, check the queue and then sleep.  If not, end.

Another way would be to have a command and control worker that monitors the other workers.  If they're all in a "hold" state, trigger a flag that they all watch to end.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Any idea how I can prevent race-conditions? For example, what happens if two workers that are in hold state checks the queue at the same time and one of them decides "end" while the other has just begun working on a page? Do you think, if it is guaranteed that a worker will not change its state before adding every page it finds to the queue, no such race-condition would occur?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the order of actions for each worker.  Hopefully this should clear up any confusion.

Comment: Let the workers talk to db via stored procedure and lock table for update/ write in procedure - that is one way. Other way would be to make your code transaction based. not sure how to do that in python.